# Elasticsearch dynamic template: don’t want field to be analyzed, only want a keyword subfield

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-template

We're using a dynamic template to specify mapping for certain fields in our index. Most text fields are not mentioned in the template, and get the default mapping to an analyzed field and a keyword subfield:

```
                      "someField" : {
                        "type" : "text",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword"
                          }
                        }
                      }
```

which is good.

The index has some fields that we don't want to be analyzed, just made keywords. However, for consistency, we want all keyword fields to be a subfield named "keyword", like the above. So this:

```
"dynamic_templates" : [

  {
    "someField" : {
      "match" : "someField",
      "mapping" : {
        "type" : "keyword",
        "norms" : false
      }
    }
  },
```

isn't suitable, as it makes "someField" itself a keyword, and we want "someField.keyword" to be the keyword field. But if I use this template:

```
"dynamic_templates" : [

  {
    "someField" : {
      "match" : "someField",
      "mapping" : {
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "norms" : false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

an analyzed "top-level" field is created as well as the keyword subfield:

```
                          "someField" : {
                            "type" : "text",
                            "fields" : {
                              "keyword" : {
                                "type" : "keyword"
                              }
                            }
                          },
```

Is there a way to not have the "someField" field mapped, only "someField.keyword"? I could set index : false for the "someField" level, but users may still try to use it, and wonder why it's not working.

EDIT: I have tried to define someField as an object type, as suggested by haltabush, but get an error. Using this template:

```
{
  "template": "test*",
  "order":    1,

    "mappings" : {
      "_default_" : {

        "dynamic_templates" : [
          {
            "someField" : {
              "match" : "someField",
              "mapping" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
}
```

When I post this document:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test-1/doc/1?pretty -d '
{
  "someField" : "some value"
}
'
```

I get this error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "object mapping for [someField] tried to parse field [someField] as object, but found a concrete value"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "object mapping for [someField] tried to parse field [someField] as object, but found a concrete value"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an object:

```
                     "someField" : {
                        "type" : "object",
                        "fields" : {
                          "keyword" : {
                            "type" : "keyword"
                          }
                        }
                      },
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but can't get it to work. Will edit the question to include this.

Comment: Oh right, when you index you'll need to index "somefield.keyword" as well, instead of just "somefield"

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand. Do you mean the source document would need to now include an actual "keyword" subfield, rather than letting the mapping create it?

Comment: SOrry for the late answer, I missed the notification. I meant this:
`curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test-1/doc/1?pretty -d '
{
  "someField": {"keyword": "some value"}
}
'`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Yep, that's what I thought you meant. That's not suitable in our case, as the incoming document shouldn't have elastic-specific fields included. However, it may help others.

Comment: Sorry to hear that